# Lambda with dynamic storage duration

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

According to cppreference.com, C++11 lambda literal syntax is only legal to use in *[direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)*. There doesn't seem to be a way to use the lambda syntax directly with the `new` operator.

I need to store a lambda function in the heap so that I can call it at some later point from a different thread. It's easy enough to make a copy of the lambda, but is there a simple way to allocate the lambda directly in the heap (dynamic storage duration) without first allocating it on the stack (automatic storage duration) and making a copy?

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

struct MyObj {
    int value;
    int copies;
    int moves;

    MyObj(int v): value(v), copies(0), moves(0) {
        printf("Created object with value %d.\n", value);
    }

    MyObj(const MyObj &other): value(other.value),
    copies(other.copies+1), moves(other.moves) { }

    MyObj(const MyObj &&other): value(other.value),
    copies(other.copies), moves(other.moves+1) { }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    MyObj o { 5 };
    // Create lambda on stack (automatic storage duration)
    auto f = [o] {
        printf("Object value is %d\n", o.value);
        printf("%d copies, %d moves...\n", o.copies, o.moves);
    };
    // Copy lambda to heap (dynamic storage duration)
    decltype(f) *g = new decltype(f)(f);
    // Call the copy
    (*g)();
    return 0;
}
```

The above program makes 2 copies of `o` (one in the capture, and another when the lambda is copied into the heap). Ideally, there would only be one copy or move, which would happen when the heap-allocated lambda captures a copy of `o`.

Comment: Why not just create a named functor and use that?

Comment: The example is simplified. Declaring functors all over the place instead of lambdas is of course possible (you can always do that), but it would make the code much more verbose/cumbersome.

Comment: I have no idea if it is legal to do this with a lambda or not(I think it is okay but can't be certain) But couldn't you make the variable static and pass it around by reference?  Something like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1a9a420bcb69b8c

Comment: @NathanOliver - Sorry for the late reply. That only works if the lambda has no closure (i.e., no captures), since a unique closure needs to be created for each dynamic instance of the lambda.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++11, a lambda expression will *always* result in some form of automatic object, whether a stack variable or an unnamed temporary. There's nothing you can do to change that.

In C++17, guaranteed elision gives us the ability to do this:

```
new auto(<lambda>)
```

This uses the memory allocated by `new` to store the result of that expression. There would be no temporary lambda object created here, nor would any copy/move constructor for the lambda be invoked. And most importantly, the language would not require that the lambda type *have* copy/move constructors that could be invoked.

You *need* guaranteed elision to ensure this however. Without that guarantee, then you're banking on the compiler to optimize it. The standard *permits* such cases to elide the copy. And yes, any compiler worth using probably would elide such copies.

With guaranteed elision, you could capture immobile types and this would still work without copying anything. Pre-C++17, your lambda would still need to have a copy or move constructor, even though the call to it is elided.

Comment: This is very helpful. I wasn't aware that C++17 was (potentially) going to have guaranteed copy elision. Thanks!

Comment: @DaoWen: Over the course of the next week, we'll find out if it makes it into C++17.

Comment: @NicolBolas Mind updating this now that guranteed copy elison is part of c++ 17?  I'd like to use it as a dupe target for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839698/is-it-possible-to-create-a-lambda-on-the-heap-in-one-step)

Comment: @NathanOliver: OK.

Answer (score 8):

The `auto` keyword is legal in `new` expressions, which allows you to do this:

```
    // Create lambda directly in heap (dynamic storage duration)
    auto g = new auto([o] {
        printf("Object value is %d\n", o.value);
        printf("%d copies, %d moves...\n", o.copies, o.moves);
    });
```

Here's the whole (updated) example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

struct MyObj {
    int value;
    int copies;
    int moves;

    MyObj(int v): value(v), copies(0), moves(0) {
        printf("Created object with value %d.\n", value);
    }

    MyObj(const MyObj &other): value(other.value),
    copies(other.copies+1), moves(other.moves) { }

    MyObj(const MyObj &&other): value(other.value),
    copies(other.copies), moves(other.moves+1) { }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    MyObj o { 5 };
    // Create lambda directly in heap (dynamic storage duration)
    auto g = new auto([o] {
        printf("Object value is %d\n", o.value);
        printf("%d copies, %d moves...\n", o.copies, o.moves);
    });
    // Call heap lambda
    (*g)();
    return 0;
}
```

The above makes just one copy of `o` as desired—at least on my platform (Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)).

Comment: That is an optimization, not a guarantee.

Comment: I'm guessing this is some sort of RVO? If it works with semi-recent Clang and GCC on OS X and Linux, then this is probably sufficient—but I'm still open to other solutions, especially if there's a more portable one!

Comment: Yes, that's copy elision (copy elision being the general term for all forms of "RVO", parameter copy elision, etc). It seems odd, but a heap allocation is no different from a stack allocation to elision.

Comment: @DaoWen It is just that RVO, NRVO is not guaranteed to be performed.  The compiler can chose not to use it.

Comment: Nice,  only one copy and no move (g++ 4.8.4)

Comment: why don't you delete it at the end?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko - I didn't bother to delete it because this is just a simple example program. My goal was to count the constructor invocations. The operating system reclaims all memory when your program exits, but in a "real" program you'd want a `delete` to match the `new`.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider something like std::make_unique instead:

```
template <typename Lambda>
std::unique_ptr<Lambda> make_unique_lambda(Lambda&& lambda)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Lambda>(
        new Lambda(std::forward<Lambda>(lambda))
    );
}

auto unique_lambda = make_unique_lambda([] () {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A polymorphic function container that can be moved across threads is a std::function, which may be direct-initialised by a lambda.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    std::function<void()> g = [o = MyObj{5}]{
        printf("Object value is %d\n", o.value);
        printf("%d copies, %d moves...\n", o.copies, o.moves);
    };

    // Call the copy
    g();

    // now *move* it to another thread and call it there

    std::thread t([my_g = std::move(g)] { my_g(); });
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

expected:

```
Created object with value 5.
Object value is 5
0 copies, 1 moves...
Object value is 5
0 copies, 1 moves...
```

Comment: This gives the result `2 copies, 1 moves`, whereas my original example only had `2 copies, 0 moves`. I.e., this does more copies+moves than the code I included in my question. My compiler also warns that `my_g = std::move(g)` is C++14, which isn't necessarily a problem, but still is important to note (we'd rather keep the dependencies as simple as possible).

Comment: if you want to minimise copies, we can do that. Will update.

Comment: Where is the benefit of moving it to `g` first, can't `f` just be moved when declared `auto`?

Comment: @FelixDombek fully optimised version posted. I was just following the op's style originally.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Please *read* the question: "*Ideally, there would only be one copy or move*". Simply turning 2 copies into 2 moves is not a solution.

Comment: @RichardHodges: This requires that the captured value be something which can be expressed as a temporary constructed within a lambda capture. As the OP explained in a comment, "The example is simplified"; the actual code may be more complex. You're too focused on making the simplified example work and not enough on the general problem of avoiding additional lambda copies.

Comment: @NicolBolas as far as I can see, the OP does not mention any difficulties in moving the lambda. One wonders what difficulties there may be, since a lambda has only one way of accessing the data stored within it (it has only one method on its interface), so non-movable structures like mutexes and so on will (should) never be be captured in a lambda unless by (possibly shared) reference. The OP is fixated on heap allocation. Heap allocation is implicit in a `std::function` for anything other than the most trivial lambda. Unless I see evidence to the contrary, this solution works and is portable

Comment: @RichardHodges: "*as far as I can see, the OP does not mention any difficulties in moving the lambda.*" So when the OP said "one copy or move," that wasn't clear enough? Move operations aren't necessarily cheap after all. The question seems quite clear; he wants to create the lambda within the heap-allocated storage, not by creating a temporary that gets transferred into that storage. Hence the phrase "*directly in the heap, without first allocating it on the stack*".

Comment: @NicolBolas the solution above, as you can see, involves one move and zero copies. That was the requirement, was it not? - " Ideally, there would only be one copy or move". 
I think I have surpassed the requirement.

Comment: @RichardHodges: As I said in a previous comment, it only involves "one move" because the variable being captured could instead be initialized directly. Providing an answer that only works with the [mcve] and not in the general case, as requested by the OP, is not a valid answer. The OP made it clear that it was *just an example*, not the totality of the issue.

Comment: @NicolBolas Forgive me, but I thought that the purpose of an MCVE in the question is to give answerers (you and me) enough information to answer the question. With the available information, the question is answered and the solution is correct. Answering questions based on what the OP may or may not really want to ask is futile. I note your answer with interest and think it is a good answer. I cannot fathom why you seem so bothered by this one. Is there something incorrect or offensive about it? If so, please send me an email setting out your concerns. hodges.r@gmail.com

Comment: @RichardHodges: "*Forgive me, but I thought that the purpose of an MCVE in the question is to give answerers (you and me) enough information to answer the question.*" So why do people put text in their questions? Why aren't questions just "here's some code; make it do Y." The text of a question is just as important, if not moreso, than the code in the question. If the text says that he wants a general solution, then a fix for that specific case which is *not* a general solution is not helpful.