# Is it possible to create a lambda on the heap in one step?

Tags: c++, c++17

We can create a lambda like this:

```
auto x = [](){};
```

I can create a copy of this on the heap like this:

```
auto y = new decltype(x)(x);
```

The question is, is it possible to do this in one step? Creating a lambda on the heap without extra steps?

Comment: I think the question should be: what is the real type of lambda? since `auto` just hide the type name.

Comment: @SHR The lambda type is unnamed: ["The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Its "real type" is usually some compiler-generated gibberish name but that doesn't help you because you cannot directly name it anyway.

Comment: answer shows that it is possible, but the real question is; WHY?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `auto` in a new-expression:

```
new auto ([](){});
```

Comment: More interesting question - is it possible to create shared lambda using `make_shared`? ;)

Comment: yes it is, here is `make_unique` example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/pR7FWQfo0SSHAKhH

Comment: @MarekR that's not exactly lambda on heap though. You create `unique_ptr` ro `std::function` which is init-ed with lambda, not unique_ptr to lambda.

Comment: @DanM. https://wandbox.org/permlink/RFX021jIRf7vBFzh